Google Play services out of date for com.domain.MyApp. Requires 212800000 but found 201817023
A few month ago I installed my app on Android Emulator and was able to run it. Yesterday I started the Emulator and tried to start previously installed version of my app, but it closed just after displaying the launch screen. I found the following in the log:
03-16 21:41:58.788 8851 8896 W GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date for com.domain.MyApp. Requires 212800000 but found 201817023
03-16 21:41:58.800 8851 8909 W GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date for com.domain.MyApp. Requires 212800000 but found 201817023
03-16 21:41:58.801 8851 8909 W GoogleApiManager: The service for com.google.android.gms.internal.appset.zzd is not available: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
03-16 21:41:59.773 6499 8770 W ConnectionTracker: Exception thrown while unbinding
03-16 21:41:59.773 6499 8770 W ConnectionTracker: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lm@dd5cef2
03-16 21:41:59.773 6499 8770 W ConnectionTracker: at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1757)
03-16 21:41:59.773 6499 8770 W ConnectionTracker: at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1874)
03-16 21:41:59.773 6499 8770 W ConnectionTracker: at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:792)
03-16 21:41:59.773 6499 8770 W ConnectionTracker: at ce.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817056@20.18.17 (040800-0):1)
03-16 21:41:59.773 6499 8770 W ConnectionTracker: at ce.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817056@20.18.17 (040800-0):5)
03-16 21:41:59.773 6499 8770 W ConnectionTracker: at ln.A(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817056@20.18.17 (040800-0):10)
03-16 21:41:59.773 6499 8770 W ConnectionTracker: at ky.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817056@20.18.17 (040800-0):3)
03-16 21:41:59.773 6499 8770 W ConnectionTracker: at dy.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817056@20.18.17 (040800-0):2)
03-16 21:41:59.773 6499 8770 W ConnectionTracker: at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
03-16 21:41:59.773 6499 8770 W ConnectionTracker: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
03-16 21:41:59.773 6499 8770 W ConnectionTracker: at iw.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@201817056@20.18.17 (040800-0):15)
03-16 21:41:59.919 8772 8791 W System : A resource failed to call end.

How to fix this? Should I update the Emulator somehow?
This happened on the emulators surrounded with the red line:

